# Home Network Setup

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, home-networking

I have moved into my new house and aw trying to set up  a new network, with new and better gear.

**Heres what my setup looks like now:**
[image: Network setupd]

What is the best way to set up the addresses? I used to have just the modem for an AP and routing so everything was just DHCP reserved and it worked most of the time but sometimes either the server needed a restart or the modem did to get internet connection back again. Which bring the next question

How does one make the printer and the server stay on the same IP after disconnect, reconnect or power loss? Both things need to be in a known place all the time for both internal and external connection.

How does port forwarding work in this set up?I used to have the server setup on 192.168.0.2:32400. so when a connection came in on (Public ip here):443 it would than be forwarded on to 192.168.0.2:32400. I picked port 443 for the incoming connection as it get around a blocked ports so the server can be accessed from work or school. I know this is the HTTPS port but does it have any effect on all incoming HTTPS connections? and Should I just port forward traffic from Modem --> Nighthawk --> Server?

Also for now all clients are wireless. I have it setup so that all 3 wireless networks (5GHz, 5GHz, 2.4GHz) are named the same with the same password so that any clients will just connect to the fastest and strongest one. they are all on different channels so they don't overlap. Is this a good idea or is there a better way?

I know this is a lot but I really appreciate the help

Comment: Probably best you split this into multiple questions. There’s a lot here.

Answer (score 0):

> How does one make the printer and the server stay on the same IP after
>   disconnect, reconnect or power loss? Both things need to be in a known
>   place all the time for both internal and external connection.

Both the server and printer will have settings to configure a static IP address. If your DHCP subnet is 192.168.1.0/24 (a pretty common one) you could give your server and printer addresses 192.168.1.2 & .3 (your router would probably be 192.168.1.1). Nothing should be given the same IP addresses via DHCP, but to be sure, you can configure the DHCP range on the router to start at a higher address such as 192.168.1.10.